# How to make selenium to interact with Microstrategy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, uiautomation

1. I have to launch the MSTR page on the new tab, by clicking on the Report Details Web Element. [image]
2. I could not find the Inspect option on the right click menu that I want to click on the mstr page
3. when I made right click away from it, I could find inspect option and all the mstr folder icons are placed in the table. I toook xpath of it and tried to click but gett[image]ing element not found 
   My question is:
   Can Selenium interact with MSTR reports? IF yes, what shall the way be? If no, which is the best tool to use and why it cannot interact?

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find the Inspect option on the right click menu that I
>   want to click on the mstr page

Just press f12 to open the inspector and use the highlight button to highlight the leement you want:

[image]

You could also use the shortcut key combination `ctrl+shift+i`:

[image]

**Why is it behaving like this:?**

Because the webpage is coded in a way to capture the mouse right click event and display a droppdown menu instead of the native browser owned.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to the answer if it it answers your problem.

Comment: Pls read my thord point, I am able to see inpect on the right click, when I inspect in away from the mstr folder.

Comment: @dhivyaN is it inside canvas ? is it inside iframe ?

Comment: is there any sample project i could look into